# Connect 2 queries

Tags: sql

I have two following queries:

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT custpersonid) AS count1 
FROM   my_precustperson 
WHERE  rsv_no = 1510708 
       AND custpersonid IS NOT NULL 

SELECT Count(*) AS count2 
FROM   my_precustperson 
WHERE  rsv_no = 1510708 
       AND custpersonid IS NULL
```

I want to plus value `count1` to `count2` (count1+count2) but I don't know how to do.
Please help me find out the best query for this situation.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The accepted answer is product specific.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT (SELECT Count(DISTINCT custpersonid) AS count1 
    FROM   my_precustperson 
    WHERE  rsv_no = 1510708 
           AND custpersonid IS NOT NULL) 
    + (SELECT Count(*) AS count2 
      FROM   my_precustperson 
      WHERE  rsv_no = 1510708 
             AND custpersonid IS NULL);
```

Comment: Is there any way to change these two query into one query?:3

Comment: The answer above is a single query that adds the results of the two queries. It preserves the logic of the two separate queries as well.

Comment: You could do it without the subqueries if you didn't need `distinct` in the first count.

Comment: Also, you can remove "AND custpersonid IS NOT NULL" from first sub-query since count(DISTINCT doesn't count NULL's.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with one `select`, with `count distinct` as before, and a conditional `COUNT` for the NULL's. (COUNT does only count non-null rows.)

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT custpersonid) AS count1,
       count(case when custpersonid IS NULL then 1 else null end) as count2 
FROM   my_precustperson 
WHERE  rsv_no = 1510708
```

ANSI SQL compliant!